# Can bimodality exist in a multivariate sense?

Tags: bimodal

Consider a hypothetical discussion about a Lotka–Volterra experiment involving foxes and rabbits:

```
> Ernie: Species is categorical. 
> Bert: In fact it is bimodal. 
> Ernie: Can you specify the units of the axis you claim species is bimodal? 
> Bert: Sorry no, because it is bimodal along several axes.
```

Ignoring whether the phenomenon is categorical or continuous, is it possible for bimodality of some quantity to exist not independently but along several axes - eg. as a function of length, height, weight, speed, and others - in the way Bert asserts?

Comment: Clearly it can! A mountainous landscape with many peaks, the peaks are the modes, the number of peaks/modes do not depend on the coordinate system of your maps!

Comment: This reminds me I should very much like to cast our favorite muppets into a rendition of Rosencrantz and Guildenstern are Dead.

Comment: The classic example to consider in this question is the nefarious saddle point. The density of observations in a particular location $(X, Y)$ may appear "clustered" along one path in two-dimensional space but appear "sparse" at the same location along another path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on the idea of a saddle point. Suppose $X \sim \text{Beta}(0.5, 0.5)$ and $Y \sim \text{Beta}(2, 2)$, independent. Then their marginal densities are depicted as below:

[image]

So $X$ has a well defined mode achieving a maximal density of 1.5 whereas $Y$ (please replace ylabel with dy) is bimodal with a maximal density of 3.

For the joint $X,Y$ process, the density can be visualized as

[image]

And it's plain to see that there are modes at (0.5, 1) and (0.5, 0) respectively. In univariate and multivariate cases you can even have measurable regions being the mode - the uniform density has the support as a mode!

Comment: This is helpful thanks.